# How to get URL parameter in internal file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Okay I have index.php in which i used  and its working fine all over the page except a form wizard form that load on a button click.

is working on entire page text (wherever i have used this) except a wizard form which loads on a button click. All the files of that wizard form are located website folders (e.g. wizard.php, wizard.js & wizard.css).

here's how wizard.php code starts:

```
<div class="wizard-container">
<div class="card wizard-card" data-color="green" id="wizardProfile">
    <form action="">
        <div class="wizard-header">
            <h3 class="wizard-title">
                GENERATE A FRESH <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> CODE
            </h3>
            <h5 style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">Our interactive generator will guide your through the process</h5>
        </div>
```

i want that  should also work in wizard form but it shows 
C:\xampp\htdocs\NameGenerator\content\hbox\html\wizard.php on line 7

Comment: EDIT first line: i used <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> and its working...
Second Paragraph's First Line: <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> is working on entire page...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT first line:** i used `<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?`> and its working... 
**Second Paragraph's First Line:** `<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>` is working on entire page...

i want that `<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>` should also work in wizard form but it shows